# Kubernetes NFS volume mount group read not working

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, groups, read-only

I'm having an issue where i'm unable to read files with 0660 permission, which indicates that the group membership doesn't work as intended.

Listing and reading files with 0664 works fine.

On the NFS host the files are owned by "www-data:www-data" on the kubernetes pod they are owned by the same user and group.

I'm out of ideas.

**Kubernetes pod**

```
$ id
uid=1000(node) gid=1000(node) groups=33(www-data),1000(node)
$ ls -l
-rw-rw----    1 www-data      www-data         226598 Jan  8 20:54 file.jpg
$ mount
nfs-server-hostname:/mnt/files on /var/files type nfs4 (ro,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.166.0.32,local_lock=none,addr=10.166.0.5)
```

**NFS host**

```
$ ls -l
-rw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 226598 Jan  8 21:54 file.jpg
```

This is my setup.

**Cluster details**

Autopilot cluster running on GKE

**Deployment details**

I have a deployment with the following directives:

***Spec***

```
volumeMounts:
- name: nfs-files
  mountPath: /var/files
```

***Volumes***

```
  volumes:
- name: nfs-files
  nfs:
    server: nfs-server-hostname
    path: /mnt/files
    readOnly: true
```

**NFS Host exports**

```
/mnt/files *.hostname(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with the interaction between Kubernetes and NFS, particularly when using the `fsGroup` `securityContext`. There are difficulties with reading from NFS-mounted volumes and it seems that the fsGroup securityConcept does not apply to [NFS mounts](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/issues/260).

If you set the proper `securityContext` for the pod configuration, you can make sure the volume is mounted with proper permissions. See this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) on how to configure a Security Context for a pod or container